# Dividing 3D tensor into Batches (Pytorch)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a tensor of shape (50,50,2). That is filled with values of a grid in (x,y). Like this.

```
r =0.5
#Sample 3D space
min = -10
max = 10
complexnum = 50j

#Sample 3D space
X,Y  = np.mgrid[min:max:complexnum,min:max:complexnum,] * r

T = np.sin(3*X) * np.sin(3*Y)


XY = np.concatenate((X.reshape((X.shape[0],X.shape[0],1)),Y.reshape((X.shape[0],X.shape[0],1))),2)
XY = torch.from_numpy(XY.astype(np.float32)).to(device)
T = T.reshape((T.shape[0],T.shape[0],1))
T = torch.from_numpy(T.astype(np.float32)).to(device)
```

I created a Neural Network that can take the XY as input and T as an output. In that is creating a function f(x,y). Now I need to create a way to train that NN using batches. The total amount of samples should be 2500 = 50 x 50. I want to divide the XY and T tensor into batches. I have tried DataLoader and creating a data set class with no luck. Is there a way I can achieve this? Are my Tensor shapes correct?

For some context, this is the custom data set I created to give to the DataLoader :

```
class CustomTrainDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, x_tensor, y_tensor):
    self.xdomain = x_tensor
    self.ydomain = y_tensor
    
def __getitem__(self, index):
    
  # I flatten them to find the ith sample  
  augxy = torch.from_numpy(np.vstack([self.xdomain[:,:,0].cpu().numpy().ravel(), self.xdomain[:,:,1].cpu().numpy().ravel()]).transpose().astype(np.float32)).to(device)

    
   augw= torch.from_numpy(np.vstack([self.ydomain.cpu().detach().numpy().ravel()]).transpose().astype(np.float32)).to(device)
    xy =  augxy[index]

    l = torch.where((self.xdomain[:,:,0] == xy[0]) )
    m = torch.where((self.xdomain[:,:,1]== xy[1]))
    
    xindex = m[0][0]
    yindex = l[1][0]
   
    
    return (self.xdomain[index],self.ydomain[index])
    

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.xdomain) * len(self.xdomain)
```

I understand I have to change __ len __ and __ getitem __. I thought by giving the a ([1,2],[1,1]) as the ith sample, and 50x50 as the total length would give me a nice batch. But instead, it gives me an array of size(2500, 2) divided into batches.

Sorry for this very basic question, I have been struggling to work with higher dimensions.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried with the dataset and dataloader ? Paste the code, explain what you intented to do with it and the blocker you faced

Comment: @trialNerror 2 days Ago I did but no one responded, That is why I did this smaller post. I will do it here.

Comment: This was my original post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455422/mini-batches-with-dataloader-and-a-3d-input-pytorch

Comment: Okay then there is something I still do not understand, can you give us a simplified version of your network and explicit what format is it expecting as input ? Is it [B,50,50,2] or [B,2500,2], or [B,2] (B being the batch size), and what is the tensor shape you would like to be able to input after having succeeded in batching ? Because I feel like you have fed your 2500 scalars (1-d) as one 2500-d tensor which is conceptually quite different.

Comment: Ok so maybe that is my miss conception. So I have pairs of (x,y) and I aggregate them into a grid structure (50,50,2), meaning I have 2500 samples of (x,y) pairs. So that is the whole data set, so I would like to dive it into bach sizes for example (12,12,2) and (12,12,1).

Comment: My network is a fully connected network, using input layer size = 2 and output size = 1.
The hidden layers in between are multiple of layers of nn.linear(128,128) and InstanceNorm1d(128) (4 in total). Using in each layer ReLu activation function in each.

Comment: Maybe a better way to look at it is by cutting a 2d image into parts and use it as the batches. Maybe DataLoader wouldn't be the best to use it.